# angular ng lint --output-file overwrites file for each project (eslint)

Tags: formatting, angular-cli, eslint, lint

I have an angular repo with multiple projects defined inside of it.

while linting, i want the output of the entire repo into a single file, so i run something like this

```
ng lint --format ./my-format.js --output-file ./reports/eslint_issues.json
```

the formatter is a basic foreach loop and dumping the results json.

**The issue is that lint runs for each project and the results are overwritten to that file each time.**

**I want a way to merge all the results of all projects into a single file.**

- platform: windows
- shell: gitbash

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

```
module.exports = function (results) {
var fs = require('fs');
var fileExists = fs.existsSync('./reports/eslint_issues.json');
var output = { issues: [] };
if(fileExists) {
    var issuesFromFile = fs.readFileSync('./reports/eslint_issues.json');
    output.issues = output.issues.concat(JSON.parse(issuesFromFile).issues);
} 
results.forEach(function (result) {
...
});
return JSON.stringify(output);
```

};